# Notificaciones emergentes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

He intentado hacer una función para alertar al usuario con una notificación pero simplemente no va, el código parece correcto pero la notificación nunca salta en el emulador.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 public void createNotificationChannel(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence name = "Notificación";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("0",name,  NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad el código que tienes es para inicializar únicamente el NotificationManager, agregando un Canal.

Necesitas ahora crear la notificación de esta forma:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default");

       mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentText(message)
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Te sugiero revises este ejemplo:

[Crear Notificación Android](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Create-Notification/)

Especificamente el método  `sendNotification(String message)` :

```
  //Create notification
    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default","Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(getRandomNumber(0,1000), mBuilder.build());
    }

    private int getRandomNumber(int min,int max) {
        return (new Random()).nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]